# use ajax returned value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

in my js script tag I hv a var that store data of my ajax success callback. let say it's $result. How can I use it in php? I don't want to directly use for example `$('#element').html($result)` to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Send it back to the PHP script that wants to use the value via another AJAX request perhaps..

Comment: PHP runs on the server, Javascript on the client, it's quite impossible to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Bartdude send javascript var to be as php var

Comment: You are missing the abc of client-server programming..

Comment: Can you put your code and elaborate the question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the response to browser instead of that you can use the request and manipulate as you want it in server side that is in php. It is not necessary to send the response back to client.

Comment: if you don't use ajax response, there is no point of sending the ajax request. You can simply post data and manipulate data with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate/Filter the result before getting it from ajax and then use it to manipulate DOM/or for whatever purpose you like.. I guess this is the best option.... Else it'll raise the iteration time and page load time.

**So just manipulate it before returning from the ajax file**

and if you wish to use it in php which will load it again then why to use ajax.

Comment: I want to show logged in users' content. how would u do the check session part in index.php if u use ajax to manipulate the dom? write the same piece of code twice?

Comment: Sorry I really didnt get you.. What is your exact problem..
but lemme tel u
Well you can check session on any page or file..